# Reuse XML Elements to make list?

Tags: xml, reusability

On S1000D, how can I lasso or retrieve all `<acronym id="acr-0001">` elements (with contained acronym text data) and make a table list out of them in a data module I'm calling "List of Acronyms"?

In other words, I want to *reuse* XML elements to make a list out of them.  What S1000D XML code do I setup in "List of Acronyms" data module so that it automatically generates a list of acronym data that is retrieved from numerous data modules once I run it through the Publisher application?

Comment: Adding your attempted code is always a good first step, especially for your first question.

Comment: Could you please format your question. This is not a forum, it has different question format culture.

Comment: Reformatted. Pls learn from that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use notepad++ and regex formula (or search&replace), like
search in all file

and in the result, you can find what are the other tag before and after <acronym___>, like . So you can write in the search window
.*<acronym id="acr-\d\d\d\d.*
with a care not to valid the search on multiple line
for S&R use this formulas
*[]<acronym*[]
and you can get the result in a specic file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).